# Move Datafactory resources from Dev to QA to Prod

Tags: github, github-actions, azure-data-factory, cicd

I was trying to understand the CICD solutions for Azure Datafactory.  I was going through [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements) related to Azure Devops.

I was looking for a similar example on how I can incrementally move ADF resources from Dev to QA to PROD using Github repos. I realize I would need github actions to do the build and deployments. I came across [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/azure-data-factory-ci-cd-with-github-actions/ba-p/3768493) which demonstrates this.

However, my question is related to how can I move my ADF resources from one environment to another. The documentation says that only the Dev ADF is connected to Git. Now let's say I build and deploy from the adf_publish branch to QA as release 1. 2 weeks later, I modify the resources in Dev ADF and publish as release 2. This alters the ARM templates in adf_publish branch. So now how do I deploy release 1 (which was successfully tested in QA) to Prod and move release 2 to QA? How do I get the reference of release 1 and and build and deploy from that to Prod?
What is the best way to achieve this?
I may also want to hotfix the release that I have in production (release 1) without moving any of the other changes (release 2) from QA to Prod.
I know we can use control and feature flags to switch functionality on or off. But is this the only way to achieve the outcome?